# How to exclude a part of a page in search results

Tags: plugins, search

I did my WordPress website design with Elementor plugin and i included a menu in the side bar of every page, now i face a problem with search results because searching any word from the menu gives a huge number of results, it's normal because i have a menu in all pages.

I want to know how can i exclude this side menu from search result?

Answer (score 0):

Copy below code and paste in function.php file to exclude pages from search results.

```
if (!is_admin()) {
    function wpb_search_filter($query) {
        if ($query->is_search) {
            $query->set('post_type', 'post');
        }
        return $query;
    }
    add_filter('pre_get_posts','wpb_search_filter');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for  your response, but what i want is to hide a part of a page from search results page not the entire page